# Difference between $ (d/dy)(y \sin 2x)$ and $(\partial/\partial y)(y \sin 2x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the difference between $ (d/dy)(y \sin2x)$ and $(\partial/\partial y)(y \sin2x)$? I think for first part, it should be $ (d/dy)(y \sin2x)=\sin2x+2y\cos 2x (dx/dy)$. But  how do we get, $(\partial/\partial y)(y \sin2x)=2cos2x$? I am not good in differential calculus, need help please. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\partial/\partial y$ in the second case? Moreover, I see no equation.

Comment: @Vasily Mitch, yes, i am.

Comment: @Vasily Mitch, i have edited my question now. May kindly be noted.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the first case. Partial derivative is easier. One just has to assume that all other varaiables are constant. Or alternatively you can take the expression for a full derivative and set $dx/dy \to 0$:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}y\sin 2x = \left(\sin 2x + 2y\frac{dx}{dy}\cos 2x\right)_{dx/dy=0} = \sin 2x
$$